# Simple animation

Tags: tikz-trees, animations

I'm trying to draw a simple TikZ tree

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1cm,
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm}]

\node{Data Mining}
    child { node {Statistiques}}
    child { node {Intelligence artificielle}}
    child { node {Informatique}}

;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I need to do a simple animation to display a node each time (first node then first and second then first second and third). If someone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome! Please can you complete your code? It matters a great deal what class you are using, for example!

Answer (score 2):

You may typeset nodes in white to hide them.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1cm, level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm}]
\node{Data Mining}
    child { node {Statistiques}}
    child[white] { node {Intelligence artificielle}}
    child[white] { node {Informatique}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1cm, level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm}]
\node{Data Mining}
    child { node {Statistiques}}
    child { node {Intelligence artificielle}}
    child[white] { node {Informatique}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1cm, level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm}]
\node{Data Mining}
    child { node {Statistiques}}
    child { node {Intelligence artificielle}}
    child { node {Informatique}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer, its not exactly what i want but i found how to do it

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (magic) [matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&, column sep=4mm, row sep=2mm]{
        \node (Info) [draw,shape=rectangle,visible on=<2->] {Informatique}; \&
        \node (data) [draw,shape=circle,visible on=<1->] {Data Mining}; \&
        \node (stat) [draw,shape=rectangle,visible on=<3->] {statistiques}; \\
        \&
        \node (Intel) [draw,shape=rectangle,visible on=<4->] {Intelligence artificielle}; \\
    };
        \draw[->, thick,visible on=<2->] (data) -- (Info);
        \draw[->, thick,visible on=<3->] (data) -- (stat);
        \draw[->, thick,visible on=<4->] (data) -- (Intel);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

thank you.